# Transparent header and background for Angular powered bootstrap modal

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using angular powered bootstrap modal. The content of the modal is an `iframe` which is a youtube video player. I want the modal body and header background colors to be transparent, so I see the backdrop instead. I just want to see the close button and the iframe. That's it.

This is the html template for my component:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close modal-x-button pull-right" (click)="activeModal.dismiss()">
        <svg class="action-icon" [svg]="'x-action.svg'" [height]="12"></svg>
    </button>
</div>

<div class="modal-backdrop modal-body">
    <iframe type="text/html" width="100%" height="400"
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/something"
            frameborder="0" [allowFullscreen]="activeModal"></iframe>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
video-modal {
  .modal-body {
    padding:0px;
    display: block;
  }
  .modal-header {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

There are a couple of issues here:

1. Is there a way to keep the close button on the header, but make the background color for the header transparent (i.e. same as backdrop)?
2. I don't like to assign `modal-backdrop` class to the modal body. Is there a way to just tell the body to be transparent and take the backdrop color?

Answer (score 2):

In the NgBootstrap doc for the modal,  you can pass a customer class to `windowClass`.

```
this.modalService.open(content, {
  ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title', 
  windowClass: 'youtube-modal-content'
}).result.then(
    result => this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`,
    reason => this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
);
```

```
.youtube-modal-content .modal-content {
  background: transparent !important;
  border: 0 !important;
}

.youtube-modal-content .modal-header,
.youtube-modal-content .modal-body,
.youtube-modal-content .modal-footer {
  border: 0 !important;
}
```

> https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api
>
> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fnxfzn

Comment: There is an issue with manipulating `modal-content` class. This condition applies to one of many modals in the app. Modals are children of window, which makes `modal-content` a global class name.

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh I edited my answer, come to find out there is a `windowClass` property option that you can pass your custom class to add to the modal window.